# Why does column = upper(column) work in Oracle but not in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

In mySQL I have to use `WHERE BINARY UPPER(col1) = col1` but in Oracle it works with no problem. Can someone explain to me why this is? I am new to mySQL.

So looking at it with the following statement

```
select upper(col1),col1
from mytable
where upper(col1) = col1;
```

Result in Oracle:

```
UPPER(COL1)          COL1               
-------------------- --------------------
JÜRGEN               JÜRGEN               
RENÉ                 RENÉ                 
CARL                 CARL
```

Result in MySQL

```
UPPER(COL1)          COL1               
-------------------- --------------------
JÜRGEN               JÜRGEN               
JÜRGEN               Jürgen               
RENÉ                 René                 
RENÉ                 RENÉ                 
CARL                 Carl                 
CARL                 CARL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String comparisons are not case-sensitive in MySQL nor SQLServer by default.

[How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/mysql-case-sensitive-string-comparison)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

[Why is SQL Server '=' comparator case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938924/why-is-sql-server-comparator-case-insensitive)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your MySQL collation is case-insensitive... so `'CARL' = 'Carl'` is true.

Answer (score 1):

Place the word BINARY between your WHERE and UPPER. That will force a case sensitive comparison